# Using binding syntax within @viewBuilder not working

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build app that shows a chess board and updates the board when the position fed to it changes. I am trying to use a Controller class as an ObservableObject:

Controller

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class BoardController: ObservableObject {

```
// Piece position
@Published var position: Position
```

Then a view is using it to set the board squares to show pieces based on a dictionary containing string values. Rectangles have a .overlay modifier:

import SwiftUI

struct BoardView: View {

```
// Squares on the chess board
private var a1 = Rectangle(), a2 = Rectangle(), 
private var a7 = Rectangle(), a8 = Rectangle(), 
...

// Controller
@ObservedObject var boardController: BoardController

init(boardController: BoardController) {
    self.boardController = boardController
}

// Chess piece overlay
@ViewBuilder func pieceOverlay(square: String) -> some View {

    if $boardController.position[square] == "K" {
        Image("white_king")
    } else if boardController.position[square] == "Q" {
        Image("white_queen")
    } else if boardController.position[square] == "R" {
    ...
}

var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {

    Text("8").bold().font(.system(size:labelSize))
        .frame(width: squareSize, height: squareSize)
    a8.fill(boardController.whiteColor)
      .frame(width: squareSize, height: squareSize)
      .overlay{pieceOverlay(square: "a8")}
     ...
  }
}
.padding()
```

}

If I use:

```
if boardController.position[square] == "K" {
```

The code compiles but changing the position dictionary fails to update the board

If I set it as a binding with a leading $ sign then code does not compile:

```
if $boardController.position[square] == "K" {
...
```

Compile error:

Referencing subscript 'subscript(_:)' on 'Binding' requires that 'Position' conform to 'MutableCollection'

Please can someone tell me how to achieve updating the view when the position changes?

Do I need to just store the position in the view as state and just replace it from outside the view?

Comment: You aren’t writing to it so no you don’t need Binding, Binding is for write access

Comment: There is not enough code here to determine what is going on. Please try to create a [mre].

Comment: You should be using `body` which is a `@ViewBuilder` and more so just make a custom `View` struct that takes the piece.

Comment: If I don't use a $ then changes to the position dictionary are not picked up by the view. The position property of the controller changes and I want those changes reflected in the view showing the board

Comment: Apologies burnsi the View is rather large so I have added it below as an answer

Comment: Thanks Maihal, I am using.a View with its body() function showing the board as Rectangles. I need to show a square as either unoccupied (no piece) or occupied (piece shown) on a given square depending on the position. So I am using a dictionary to say what piece is where and as it changes I need the view (squares of the board) to update whether they show a piece or not as moves are made